# How to express subClassOf and subPropertyOf in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

I want to use ArangoDB to store data in Knowledge Graph.

But I meet a problem:

There are `rdfs:subClassOf` and `rdfs:subPropertyOf` in RDFs, and if I want to express these two relations in ArangoDB, what should I do?

For example, how to express :

```
"[Actor]-subClassOf-[Celebrity]-subClassOf-[Person]"
```

and

```
"[mother]-subPropertyOf-[relative]-subPropertyOf-[personal_relationship]".
```

Comment: I assume you didn't want to use RDFs but create edges that is similar to them. ArangoDB didn't use RDF nor LPG, I just wanted it to be clear.

Comment: @Gilles-AntoineNys In ArangoDB, I do create edges to express these relations(subClassOf, subPropertyOf, instanceOf), but these edges seems not to have any semantic information(while rdfs:subClassOf in RDF have). So, if there are classes(Actor, Militarist, Scientist, Celebrity and Person), instances of classes and relations among them(expressed by edges) in ArangoDB, how to query all Person in ArangoDB. (Given that [Actor]-subClassOf-[Celebrity],[Militarist]-subClassOf-[Celebrity],[Scientist]-subClassOf-[Celebrity],[Celebrity]-subClassOf-[Person])

Comment: Your question is already resolved here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015945/sparql-interface-for-arangodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015945/sparql-interface-for-arangodb)